# Using Wordpress Force Login plugin to have security feature for only a certain page. An error keeps popping up and i cant seem to find it

Tags: wordpress

I can't see anything wrong with the code, this is the error below and this is the link to where i got it https://www.greengeeks.com/tutorials/force-login-before-visitors-access-wordpress/

Error:
Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 15 of file wp-content/themes/flatsome/functions.php. Please fix and try saving again.

syntax error, unexpected 'mstyle' (T_STRING), expecting ']'

Code:
[ht_message mstyle=”info” title=”” show_icon=”” id=”” class=”” style=”” ]
function my_forcelogin_redirect( $url ) {
return home_url( ‘/mypage/’ );
}
add_filter( ‘v_forcelogin_redirect’, ‘my_forcelogin_redirect’ );[/ht_message]

Comment: I don't really understand why the tutorial is telling you to paste a shortcode inside the function.php file... that's not php code. you should remove the following: `[ht_message mstyle=”info” title=”” show_icon=”” id=”” class=”” style=”” ]` and `[/ht_message]`

Comment: I suspect that's just an epic-fail-coincidence: the site greengeeks is itself on wordpress, and I think the article's author used that shortcode in order to properly format the displayed code, but that shortcode is not working anymore, hence it is simply printed as text. This is extremely confusing, because is seems that the shortcode is part of the code snippet, when it's not! :)